# Hacer que dos Radio button estén en formato lista

Tags: html, angularjs

Estoy trabajando con Angularjs y tengo dos Radio button. Los tengo alineados y lo quiero es que estén uno debajo del otro y no soy capaz de hacerlo a pesar de buscar por Internet. Os adjunto una foto de como lo tengo ahora.

[image: Abanca radio button]

También os dejo aqui mi código Html además del codigo de java script:

Código html.

```
       { <div class="form-check">
            <label  class="form-check-label" ng-repeat="option in radioOptions">
                <input type="radio" ng-model="formulario.tipo" value="{{option.value}}" ng-required="!formulario.tipo" checked>
                {{option.name}}

            </label>

        </div>}
```

Código javaScript:

```js
angular.module('formApp', [])
.controller('formAppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.radioOptions = [
        { name: 'Crédito hipotecario', value: 'Crédito hipotecario' },
        
        { name: 'Crédito personal', value: 'Crédito personal' },
    ];
    $scope.contenedor = {};
    $scope.contenedor.cantidad = "";
    $scope.contenedor.cuota = "";
    $scope.contenedor.plazos = "";
    $scope.contenedor.tipo ="";

    $scope.formulario = {}
    $scope.formulario.cantidad = 0;
    $scope.formulario.plazos = 0;
    $scope.formulario.tipo = "";

    var logresultado = function (respuesta) {
        $scope.contenedor.cantidad = respuesta.cantidad;
        $scope.contenedor.cuota = respuesta.cuota;
        $scope.contenedor.plazos = respuesta.plazos
        $scope.contenedor.tipo = respuesta.tipo;
    };

    $scope.showMe = false;


    $scope.myForm = function () {

        var baseURL = 'http://localhost:58498/api/cuota?';
        var cantidad = 'cantidad=' + $scope.formulario.cantidad;
        var plazos = '&plazos=' + $scope.formulario.plazos;
        var tipo = '&tipo=' + $scope.formulario.tipo;

        $http.get(baseURL+cantidad+plazos+tipo).success(function (respuesta) {

            console.log(respuesta)
            logresultado(respuesta);

        console.log('entra aqui')
        $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe;

        })
       
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes introducirlos en una lista `ul` e introducir cada uno de los elementos en un `li` distinto. Por último, utilizar `display:block` en estos últimos.

Ejemplo:

```css
li{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li  style="">
     <input class="radio" type="radio" name="custom_type" value="public" />Crédito hipotecario
     </li>
     <li>
     <input class="radio" type="radio" name="custom_type" 
     value="private" id="custom_venuetype_private" />Crédito personal
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias!

Comment: @SilviaGarcia De nada! Me alegra haberte ayudado :)

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando bootstrap:

```
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2</label>
</div>
<div class="radio disabled">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" disabled>Option 3</label>
</div>
```